# One Frontend for multiple shops?

Tags: frontend

I want to ask if it is possible (with modules?) to get multiple shops running with just one frontend? So I can have say 5 companies selling all their products in one onlineshop - that is maybe more attractive for customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you are asking it sounds like you are trying to setup what is called a multi-vendor environment. There are a number of 3rd party extensions which accomplish this but it is not default Magento functionality.

If you do a google search for "magento multi vendor" you'll find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's possible.

If you mean frontend==layout -> You must only create 5 stores and setup same theme in each store.

If you mean frontend==domain -> You must create 5 stores and setup different domains for each store.

If you mean something else, write :)